# Best way to amplify two analog signals and keep the differential sign

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I have an analog sensor with two outputs. Each channel output can range from +0.4 to +0.6V. Currently I am reading them with a 16 bit ADC, and subtracting them after each recording.

It would be nice to amplify them. It would be super nice to get a single signal out. I am getting an opamp shipped to me tomorrow, two Ti TL072ACP 8 pin ICs.
My sensor acts such that sometimes channel 1 is say +0.45 and channel 2 is +0.55, but sometimes channel 1 is +0.55 and channel 2 is +0.45, it is critical I keep track of which channel is high if I were to go with a single output from my opamp.
So currently the differential voltage can be positive as well as negative. Forgive me if this is too simple of a question but I can't make any mistakes, and need to be 100% certain I have it wired correctly and keep the differential sign (+/-V) relative to the signal.

Both analog channels need to be treated the same, as each has equal weight in determining the sensor reading. It makes me nervous to call one channel inverting and the other non-inverting. Both channels measure in the same way, just give their readings under different conditions. Sometimes one is high sometimes the other is high. The sensors cannot give negative results either as they are actually 2 discrete photodiodes pointing in different directions, and each generates voltage based on exposure to light. Imagine it as a sundial that I can use to tell the "time" by reading where the sun is in the sky with the sensor pair facing East-West.
I have a 5V supply on the board the contains the photodiodes (they are actually part of a CMOS microchip) and was planning to add a tap to power the opamp.

Comment: So you want a unipolar output at Vcc/2 when Vdiff=0 and a gain of 30 or 50? with a LPF of 10Hz to reject noise?  That FET OP Amp is not a great choice and wont work on 0 to 5V. What else do you have?

Comment: I can order another opamp. Suggestions on which one?

Comment: A LPF would be helpful as well. I don't know what to buy to add one.

Comment: When Vdiff = 0 (which can happen) I need it to read 0.0V

Comment: Define range of voltages East-West

Comment: LM324 series are low−cost, quad operational amplifiers with
true differential inputs. They have several distinct advantages over
standard operational amplifier types in single supply applications. The
quad amplifier can operate at supply voltages as low as 3.0 V or as
high as 32 V

Comment: They both read between +0.44 and +0.56V depending on where the "sun" is in the sky. Like I tried to say when one is low (+0.45V) the other is high (+0.54) say in the morning and vice versa in the evening.

Comment: I suggest if using 5V ...  Ch (1)  2.5 to 5V Ch (2) 0 to 2.5  with a Vdiff=0.1 and a gain of 20 you get 2.5 +/-2V

Comment: So I can take out that offset after the fact? This help is much appreciated. That being said, I don't know how to bump Ch1 up to 2.5V to 5V or Ch2 to 0V to 2.5V

Comment: this is not a free shopping design forum, You dont , the amplifier does.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Tl1e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sorry you have to find someone else to make this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103723/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75-best-way-to-amplify-two-an). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).